# Why SED man -i option doesn't have description?

Tags: linux, sed

My Sed's man outputs this:

```
Zero- or One- address commands
   =      Print the current line number.

   a \

   text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

   i \

   text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

   q [exit-code]
```

I was trying to figure out how to do in-place edit, and seems that the switch is `-i` but I couldn't see it before because my man doesn't have its description, any clue of why?

Comment: Just for your information, you can search in man files by typing slash `/` and the string you want to search. For example `/-i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're seeing the wrong part of the man page. Try the [description section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sed.1.html#contenttoc2):

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

EDIT: This assumes GNU sed.

Comment: Lol, forgivable because i'm newbie :P

Comment: @jorge, if this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: Note that this applies to GNU `sed`. The BSD `sed` requires you to put a space after `-i` and the backup extension.

Comment: And it doesn't seem to be supported by POSIX at all.